How can I specify the creation of volumes for PodTemplate in the values.yaml for Jenkins Helm Chart?
How can I specify the creation of volumes for my PodTemplate in the values.yaml for Jenkins Helm Chart Kubernetes?
It is not created like this:
agent:
  podTemplates:
    appBuilder: |
      - name: app-builder
        label: app-builder
        serviceAccount: jenkins
        containers:
          - name: app-builder
            image: ""
            command: "/bin/sh -c"
            args: "cat"
        volumes:
          - type: HostPath
            hostPath: /var/run/docker.sock
            mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock

This variant creates volume only for the default template:
agent:
  volumes:
    - type: HostPath
      hostPath: /var/run/docker.sock
      mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
  podTemplates:
    appBuilder: |
      - name: app-builder
        label: app-builder
        serviceAccount: jenkins
        containers:
          - name: app-builder
            image: ""
            command: "/bin/sh -c"
            args: "cat"


The correct variant:
agent:
  podTemplates:
    appBuilder: |
      - name: app-builder
        label: app-builder
        serviceAccount: jenkins
        containers:
          - name: app-builder
            image: ""
            command: "/bin/sh -c"
            args: "cat"
        volumes:
          - hostPathVolume:
              hostPath: /var/run/docker.sock
              mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock

